# Multi-layer elements in HTML Email for Outlook 2007 and 2010

Tags: html, email, html-email

Hope everyone is enjoying this wonderful Aloha Friday, I have a question about HTML emails. With specific regard to outlook 2007 and 2010.

I'm working on a project that involves overlaying a few PNGs on top of eachother, in fact not even a few, just 2.

The current solution that works for pretty much the rest of my market is

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td valign="top" rowspan="2" style="padding-left:7px;padding-top:17px">
        <img src="path/to/image.jpg" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="path/to/image.jpg" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This works awesome, and would be great if Outlook 07 and 2010 still supported  attribute.

So I've been looking around and I saw this tutorial on using VML http://blog.oxagile.com/2010/04/23/background-images-for-outlook-2007-and-outlook-2010-beta/ to layer images. With that said, I'm more than willing to give this a try but for simplicity sake I'd like to see if anyone has a more elegant solution than this "IF MS SOFTWARE INCLUDE DIFFERENT CODE HERE" type of deal.

Please let me know what you folks think/know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS support is limited in Outlook 2007 and 2010, so proprietary solutions are the only option.

Comment: Could you give a example of what would work? I am having the same problem. Thank you

Comment: campaignmonitor has [one](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3363/updated-applying-a-background-image-to-html-email/) or [two](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1777/body-background-images-outlook/) posts with good examples.